# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS freezes on HP X360 COnvertible 11-ab0xx

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, touchpad

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS freezes on HP X360 COnvertible 11-ab0xx while watching UTube videos and also while scrolling through TradeMe.co.nz (similar to Craigslist).
I boot my PC every morning and use it for about 4 hours and then leave it on until later in the evening.
I have found that Ubuntu freezes on my PC when I watch UTube videos or scroll through TradeMe.co.nz (similar to Craigslist).
When it freezes I have no response from the keyboard, wireless mouse, touchpad or touch screen - having to resort to the long power key press to get the pc to power off and then reboot it.

Can anyone shed some light on this problem which has been happening for about two months now ??

In response to guiverc > I will try the (Ctrl+Alt+F4) when the next freeze hits.  I do not have a SysRq key  on my keyboard - there is a [ins/prt sc] key between the [F12/Airplane] and [delete] keys. but this does not seem to work when the freeze hits.

In response to Nate T > I will need to educate myself on GUI "health monitor" overlays and the (top) command.  More information when I have it.

Comment: No response from keyboard?  So you've tried switching to a text terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F4 for example) and that didn't work, no response to SysRq commands to tell the kernel to shutdown/reboot/kill-GUI cleanly? thus why you've resorted to a power-button fix.  I'd be starting to check hardware if SysRq commands aren't working, and nothing exists in logs (`dmesg` won't be helpful due to forced power-off, but systemd journals may still contain clues)....  Did you try SysRq or (non-GUI) keyboard commands?  That's useful detail.

Comment: Also it may be a good idea to look into options for GUI "health monitor" overlays. If nothing else, you can run the `top` command in a small semi-transparent window continuously, although I am sure that much better options exist. XD. If you really have no options after the fact, then the only option left is to be vigilant before-hand. You need to find out which process(es) / events are bringing it down. I would recommend searching 'health monitor' in apt. Plug the results' names into google for more info. Ideally, you'd want something that occasionally logs results in a configurable manner.

Comment: I would try to monitor memory, processes, and maybe gpu, although if you cannot even pull up a tty, i would concentrate on the first two. At least this will give us some more info to go from.

Comment: What is the CPU there?